How to use the output of a CONCAT() function as an array in Excel
I would like to use the output of a CONCAT() function as the title for an array within XLOOKUP().  The XLOOKUP() formula I am using that works is:
=XLOOKUP(MetricDesired,'2023-12-13_000_Report.txt'!$C:$C,'2023-12-13_000_Report.txt'!D:D)
However, I would like the lookup and return arrays to come from multiple files which index the "000" in the file name up to "001" and so on. I have these file names in a separate column (column B) with the hope of using the text in that column as part of the arrays, but I tried using the following formula and it outputs #N/A:
=XLOOKUP(MetricDesired,CONCAT("'",$B3,"'!$C:$C"),CONCAT("'",$B3,"'!D:D"))
I tried CONCAT() as a way to automate the filenames in the data retrieval but I suspect the result of that function is not suitable for an array name.

Posted a comment just now for you - not sure where it went, but won't type it again.

The solution for you:
=XLOOKUP(MetricDesired,INDIRECT(CONCAT("'",$B3,"'!$C:$C")),INDIRECT(CONCAT("'",$B3,"'!D:D")))

The INDIRECT function returns the reference specified by a text string.
If you like to return values from all sheets specified somewhere in the column B (e. g. B1:B10):
=MAP(
  B1:B10,
  LAMBDA(
    t,
    XLOOKUP(MetricDesired,INDIRECT(CONCAT("'",t,"'!$C:$C")),INDIRECT(CONCAT("'",t,"'!D:D")))
  )
)


CONCAT creates text, XLOOKUP requires a reference: a matrix or array that it will lookup
You can create references with INDIRECT("text") or related formulas, they don't return text as results, but references to cells or areas
